# Password Digest is being returned in log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bcrypt

I was authenticating using bcrypt and knock gem for my rails api app and noticed that every time I return the user details, password digest is being returned as well in clear text in the log file.

Here's the log file output:

```
  ↳ app/controllers/v1/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `create'
  User Create (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("email", "first_name", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["email", "nsantiago@example.cosm"], ["first_name", "Norman"], ["password_digest", "$2a$12$am0rzVPRzgRe5eMmQd/USuOrtiM.JMbpwVd.WsD6ep7KbbIdFaVzS"], ["created_at", "2020-02-23 12:29:43.030356"], ["updated_at", "2020-02-23 12:29:43.030356"]]
  ↳ app/controllers/v1/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `create'
   (38.1ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/controllers/v1/registrations_controller.rb:4:in `create'
Completed 201 Created in 405ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 46.1ms | Allocations: 9537)
```

and here's my controller:

```
  def create
    @user = User.new(data)
    if @user.save
      render json: serialize(@user), status: 201
    else
      render json: @user.errors, status: 422
    end
  end
```

and the serializer:

```
class UserSerializer
  include FastJsonapi::ObjectSerializer
  attributes :id, :email, :full_name
end
```

Is there a way to filter the password digest output in the log?

Comment: Have you tried using [`config.filter_parameters`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)? I'm not sure if it works for query parameters though ..

Comment: Yes, password digest is part of my filter_parameters and it didn't work.